# Calculated column that takes a date field and sets the value to the first day of that month

Tags: calculated-column

Is it possible to create a calculated column that takes a date field and sets the value to the first day of that month?

I want to create a view that only shows the current month events. Basically, I do NOT want to see past month events in my view.

Answer (score 2):

You need two calculated columns and apply filter

1. Start of the Month

   ```
   =DATE(YEAR(DateField),MONTH( DateField),1)
   ```
2. End of the Month

   ```
   =DATE(YEAR( DateField ),MONTH( DateField)+1,1)-1
   ```
3. Filter

   ```
   "Start of the Month" is Less than or Equle to [Today]

   Or

   "End of the Month" is Greater than or Equal to [Today]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(MONTH([Date]),"/1/",YEAR([Date]))
```

Answer (score 1):

A formula like below should do the trick:

```
=CONCATENATE(MONTH(DATE_FIELD_NAME),"/1/",YEAR(DATE_FIELD_NAME))
```